# How to add audio to UIButtons in a TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Using Swift I have been trying to figure out how to add individual audio files to each UIButton in each cell. I have only been able to make one audio file work, but the file appends itself to each button in each cell. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

public extension UITableView {
    func indexPathForView(_ view: UIView) -> IndexPath? {
        let origin = view.bounds.origin
        let viewOrigin = self.convert(origin, from: view)
        let indexPath = self.indexPathForRow(at: viewOrigin)
        return indexPath
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    let elements = ["horse", "cat", "dog", "potato", "horse", "cat", "dog", "potato", "horse", "cat", "dog", "potato"]
    let animalSounds = ["horse1", "cat1", "dog1", "potato1", "horse2", "cat2", "dog2", "potato2", "horse3", "cat3", "dog3", "potato3"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return elements.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! UITableTableViewCell

        cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.cellView.frame.height / 2

        cell.animalLabel.text = elements[indexPath.row]
        cell.animalImage.image = UIImage(named: elements[indexPath.row])
        cell.animalImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.animalImage.frame.height / 2
        cell.animalImage.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.playAnimalSound.actions(forTarget: "playAnimalNoises", forControlEvent: UIControlEvents.allEditingEvents)
        cell.playAnimalNoises.button
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func playAnimalNoises(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForView(sender) //worked as sender
        //playSounds(soundFileName: animalSounds)
        print("Button pressed @ ")
    }

    func playSounds(soundFileName: String){
        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundFileName, withExtension: "wav")
        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
        }
        catch {
            print("Somethings wrong...")
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}

// button shown in each cell,
```

If you need me to explain any further, let me know.

Comment: Your code in `cellForRowAt` does not make any attempt to set an action for the button.

Comment: I deleted it in frustration, but I have no idea on how to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to properly add a target/action to the cell's button.

Remove:

```
cell.playAnimalSound.actions(forTarget: "playAnimalNoises", forControlEvent: UIControlEvents.allEditingEvents)
cell.playAnimalNoises.button
```

and add:

```
cell.playAnimalSound.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playAnimalNoises), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Then update `playAnimalNoises`:

```
@objc func playAnimalNoises(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let point = self.tableView.convert(sender.bounds.origin, from: sender)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    playSounds(soundFileName: animalSounds[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: along with commenting out the extensions of UITableView this completely solved my problem. If you don't mind could you further explain what you did? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What part do you need further help with?